# How to write chemical formula with branching and with labels for each branch

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, chemistry, subequations

I would like to express a chemical reaction, which can lead to multiple products (has multiple branches). This is usually expressed using a forked arrow as in the example equation (1) below. I wrote a hacky solution to achieve this using tikz:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document} 
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm and 1.2cm]
\node (A) 
    {$\text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2$};
\node[above right=of A] (B) 
    {$\text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} \qquad \Delta{H}^0 = -1.9~ \text{eV}$\qquad\hypertarget{eq1a}{(\text{1a})}
    };
\node[below right=of A] (C)    
    {$\text{H}_3^+ + \text{N} ~~\qquad \Delta{H}^0 = -0.8~ \text{eV}$\qquad\hypertarget{eq1b}{(\text{1b})}};
    \draw[-stealth] (A) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.3!(B.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (B.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
    \draw[-stealth] (A) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.3!(C.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (C.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq1} has branches (\hyperlink{eq1a}{1a}) and (\hyperlink{eq1b}{1b}).

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq2}
\begin{align}
\label{eq2a}
    \text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2& \xrightarrow{k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} &\Delta{H}^0 &= -1.9~ \text{eV} \\
\label{eq2b}
       & \xrightarrow{k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{H}_3^+ + \text{N}  &\Delta{H}^0 &= -0.8~ \text{eV} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq2} has branches \eqref{eq2a} and \eqref{eq2b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there are a few issues with it:

I dont know how to label the branches so that I can refer to them with `eqref` (as in equation (2) in the example). I am numbering the labels manually, which is not feasible in practice.

I don't know how to make the branch labels right-aligned as in the equation (2).

Does anyone know a better solution? I guess this must be a frequent problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal using `empheq`. (I am also loading `siunitx` but keep your distances.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document} 
\begin{subequations}\label{eq1}
\begin{empheq}[left={\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A)]
\node (A) 
    {$\text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2$};
    \draw[-stealth] (A.east) -- ++(0.3,0) |- ++(2,0.3) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
    \draw[-stealth] (A.east) -- ++(0.3,0) |- ++(2,-0.3) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}}]{align}
    ~\Delta{H}^0 &= -1.9~\si{\eV}\label{eq1a}\\
    ~\Delta{H}^0 &= -0.8~\si{\eV}\label{eq1b}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq1} has branches \eqref{eq1a} and \eqref{eq1b}.

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq2}
\begin{align}
\label{eq2a}
    \text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2& \xrightarrow{k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} &\Delta{H}^0 &= -1.9~\si{\eV} \\
\label{eq2b}
       & \xrightarrow{k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{H}_3^+ + \text{N}  &\Delta{H}^0 &= -0.8~\si{\eV} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq2} has branches \eqref{eq2a} and \eqref{eq2b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

And another proposal without `empheq` but a simple overlay `tikzpicture` that allows you to keep much of your original Ti*k*Z code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\begin{document} 
\begin{subequations}\label{eq1}
\begin{align}
    \hspace*{5cm}\tikznode{DH1}{\Delta{H}^0} &= -1.9~\si{\eV}\label{eq1a}\\
    \tikznode{DH2}{\Delta{H}^0} &= -0.8~\si{\eV}\label{eq1b}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq1} has branches \eqref{eq1a} and \eqref{eq1b}.

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node (A) at ($(DH1.west)!0.5!(DH2.west)+(-4,0)$) {$\text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2$};
\draw[-stealth] (A.east) -- ++(0.3,0) |- ([xshift=-1mm]DH1.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
\draw[-stealth] (A.east) -- ++(0.3,0) |- ([xshift=-1mm]DH2.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{subequations}
\label{eq2}
\begin{align}
\label{eq2a}
    \text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2& \xrightarrow{k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} &\Delta{H}^0 &= -1.9~\si{\eV} \\
\label{eq2b}
       & \xrightarrow{k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{H}_3^+ + \text{N}  &\Delta{H}^0 &= -0.8~\si{\eV} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq2} has branches \eqref{eq2a} and \eqref{eq2b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to use the second option using TikZ overlay. In this case, the arrows, are linked to the formulas using the `tikznode`s and automatically adjust position if the formula changes in size.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution along the lines of what you were doing for giving equation style labels to tikz diagrams. It defines an option `eqn-label` for a node which puts an equation number on the right hand side of the page on level with the current node. This uses the `current page` node so you need to include the `remember picture` option in the `tikzpicture` options.

I made this by modifying the definition of the `label` key. The `label` key is defined on line 762 of the core tikz file `tikz.code.tex` but the command that actually does the work is `\tikz@@parse@label@nonactive` which is defined on line 830.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    eqn-label/.style={
      append after command = {%
        \bgroup
          [current point is local=true]
          \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikz@node@is@a@labelfalse
            \pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{east}
            \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
            \pgfpointanchor{\tikz@last@fig@name}{center}
            \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
          }
          node [every label,
                left
                ] at (\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya) {\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{(\@currentlabel)}\!\!}
          \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}
        \egroup}
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm and 1.2cm, remember picture]
\node (A)
    {$\text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2$};
\node[above right=of A, eqn-label=eq1a] (B)
    {$\text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} \qquad \Delta{H}^0 = -1.9~ \text{eV}$};
\node[below right=of A, eqn-label=eq1b] (C)
    {$\text{H}_3^+ + \text{N} ~~\qquad \Delta{H}^0 = -0.8~ \text{eV}$};
    \draw[-stealth] (A) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.3!(B.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (B.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
    \draw[-stealth] (A) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.3!(C.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (C.west) node[auto,pos=0.7] {${\scriptstyle k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq1} has branches \eqref{eq1a} and \eqref{eq1b}.

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq2}
\begin{align}
\label{eq2a}
    \text{NH}^+ + \text{H}_2& \xrightarrow{k^\text{a}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{NH}_2^+ + \text{H} &\Delta{H}^0 &= -1.9~ \text{eV} \\
\label{eq2b}
       & \xrightarrow{k^\text{b}_{\text{NH}^+}} \text{H}_3^+ + \text{N}  &\Delta{H}^0 &= -0.8~ \text{eV}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
where equation \eqref{eq2} has branches \eqref{eq2a} and \eqref{eq2b}.
\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to implement equation numbering within TikZ, very interesting and useful. If I had a document with many TikZ pictures to label, I would definitely use it. However, my documents usually contain just one to two such equations and lot of simple equations, so I am sticking with the approach of @marmot, which seems simpler at this point.